# Sorting a file then storing that into a new file using Python

Tags: python, file, sorting

so I have to sort a file in alphabetical order which isn't my problem. I can do that, but my problem is writing that sorted list into a new file. Here is what I have.

```
import os
os.chdir("/Users/User/Documents") #(I put my name where it says "User")

user_file = open("info.txt", "r")
file = user_file.read()
file_string = file.split("\n")

file_string.sort()
print(file_string) #This is here just so I can see that it sorted correctly

end_file = open("write.txt", "w")
for item in file_string:
    end = end_file.write(str(item))
    print(end)
```

Ok, so my info.txt is what needs to be alphabetized and it is just a list of colors. So my last 4 lines is where I'm struggling. I'm trying to take each item in the file_string and write those into a new file, but print(end) gives me how many characters they are. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Well, aren't the items in the file? (If you can't find the file, it's in your `Documents` dir.)

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it this way instead. Yes, this is the full solution.

```
import os
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\<username>\Documents')
lines = open("info.txt", "r").readlines()
lines.sort()
with open("write.txt", "w") as out:
    out.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `write()` method returns the number of bytes written, so it's working as designed.

You want to write newlines to your file, though (since you removed them from the original file when splitting on newlines), and you mustn't forget to close it, so

```
for item in file_string:
    end_file.write(item + "\n")
end_file.close()
```

would work correctly.

A better solution, though, would be:

```
with open("info.txt", "r") as user_file:
    file = user_file.readlines()
file.sort()
with open("write.txt", "w") as end_file:
    end_file.writelines(file)
```

or even

```
with open("info.txt", "r") as user_file, open("write.txt", "w") as end_file:
    end_file.writelines(sorted(user_file.readlines()))
```

Comment: What do you mean "print the end_file"? If you want to print the sorted lines on-screen, just do `for line in file: print(line)`

Comment: Or `print("".join(line for line in file))`

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.x [`file.write`](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) returns the number of characters written to the file, you don't need to worry about that.

The only problem I can think of is that you're not adding any `'\n'` after words, so all items wind up writing on the same line.

```
with open("write.txt", "w") as f:
    for item in file_string:
        end_file.write(item + '\n')
```